# query for the records should append based on id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have  few columns in my **sqlserver** db:

```
1. Case id
2. Comments
```

Here case id occurs multiple times, means for the same case id i have different comments in different rows.

Example:

```
Case1 -- low performance
Case2 -- Average
case3 --- Good
Case1 --- Performance improved,
Case2 -- good
```

I need to pull the case id and Comments from db, if the case id exits more than once, comments should be appended in that comments column.

Comment: Group by, group_concat....?

Comment: Use `FOR XML PATH()`. GROUP_CONCAT works only in MySQL.
http://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #a
(
    case_id VARCHAR(10),
    Comments VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO #a VALUES('Case1', 'low performance');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES('Case1', 'Performance improved');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES('Case2', 'Average');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES('Case3', 'Good');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES('Case2', 'good');



SELECT     distinct c1.case_id,
            STUFF((    SELECT ',' + a.Comments AS [text()]
                        FROM #a a
                        WHERE
                        a.case_id = c1.case_id
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 1, '' )
            AS s
FROM #a c1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT Case_id, Comments = STUFF((
                                  SELECT ',' + md.Comments
                                  FROM your_tab yt 
                                  WHERE m. Case_id = yt. Case_id  
                                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM your_tab m
ORDER BY m.Case_id
```

this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @a TABLE 
(
    case_id VARCHAR(10),
    Comments VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO @a VALUES('Case1', 'low performance');
INSERT INTO @a VALUES('Case1', 'Performance improved');
INSERT INTO @a VALUES('Case2', 'Average');
INSERT INTO @a VALUES('Case3', 'Good');
INSERT INTO @a VALUES('Case2', 'good');


select DISTINCT ss.case_id,
SUBSTRING(
(select ','+  s.Comments from @a s 
               where  s.case_id = ss.case_id  
                order by Comments for xml path('')),2,2000) as CSV
from @a ss
```